# mongoose getter and socket.io

Tags: mongodb, node.js, mongoose

Let's say I have a Person model, and Person's schema defines a key for a phone number with a getter for formatting. When I find a document from the database and look at the value: `console.log(doc.phone)`, I see a properly formatted phone number. When I transmit the doc over socket.io, the client only sees the unformatted version of phone.

**What is the best way to ensure the the client sees the properly formatted data?**

---

console.log(doc.phone):

`(555) 123-4567`

console.log(doc):

`{ phone: '5551234567',
  _id: 4ee1aa57053868bb13000002 }`

I'm transmitting an array of them over socket.io like so:

`socket.emit('people', docs)`

Comment: How do you transmit the doc over socket.io and also can you paste the output of console.log(doc.phone) please?

Comment: Yes, I just updated the question with the code and output.

Comment: That's really strange, but I don't think the error is from Socket.IO, I think you are either formatting the code later or something similar.. check your code

Comment: Yeah I found it has to do with the magic of how mongoose getters work, and nothing to do with socket.io.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question, I had to override toJSON on the schema like so:

```
PersonSchema.methods.toJSON = ->
  obj = @toObject()
  obj.phone = @phone
  obj
```